# Is there a Zod method that will mutate the key?

Tags: javascript, zod

Given this schema, mutate the key "user_id" to "user":

```
const schema = z.object({
    user_id: z.string() // <--- some method here to mutate the key,
});

let input = { user_id: 1234qwer5678 }

let output = schema.parse( input )

console.log(output) // returns { id: 1234qwer1234 }
```

Comment: The wording of your question makes it slightly ambiguous which key you want: `user` or `id`. I went with the first thing you said, but the code is showing `id` in the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#transform) to modify the data after it has been parsed by the underlying schema. So for example:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  user_id: z.string(),
}).transform(({ user_id, ...rest }) => ({
  user: user_id,
  ...rest
});
```

This will accept an object with `user_id` as the field but when parsing will return the value under the `user` key instead.